# Exterior differentiation, changing variables

Tags: analysis

Let $\eta=a(x,y,z)dx\wedge dy+b(x,y,z)dy\wedge dz+c(x,y,z)dx \wedge dz$. How to express $\eta$ in spherical coordinates, that is in form of $\Phi^{\ast}\eta=A(r,\theta,\varphi)dr\wedge d\theta+B(r,\theta,\varphi)dr\wedge d\varphi+C(r,\theta,\varphi)d\theta \wedge d\varphi$? Exterior product of derivatives is a totally new concept for me and I'm not quite sure how to go from $dx\wedge dy$ to $dr\wedge d\theta$ etc. Do I just calculate it and then extract the product I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you an example in 2 dimensions and let us know if you can take it from there. Suppose that we are in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and want to switch from $dx \wedge dy$ to $dr \wedge d\theta$. In this case, $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$. Therefore $dx = d(r \cos(\theta)) = \cos(\theta) dr - r \sin(\theta) d\theta$ and $dy = d(r \sin(\theta)) = \sin(\theta) dr + r \cos(\theta) d\theta$. Now 
\begin{align*}
&dx \wedge dy = (\cos(\theta)\, dr - r \sin(\theta)\,d\theta) \wedge (\sin(\theta)\, dr + r \cos(\theta)\, d\theta) \\
&=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \,dr \wedge dr + r \cos^2(\theta)\, dr \wedge d\theta - r \sin^2(\theta) \,dr \wedge d\theta + r^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) \,d\theta \wedge d\theta\\
&=(r \cos^2(\theta) + r \sin^2(\theta))\, dr \wedge d\theta = r \, dr \wedge d\theta
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $dr \wedge dr = d\theta \wedge d\theta = 0$ and $dr \wedge d\theta = - d\theta \wedge dr$. Can you go analogize to 3 dimensions now?

Comment: Absolutely, appreciated :)